# Vue 3 Composition API - watchEffect vs. watch

Tags: vue.js, watch, vue-composition-api

So I have been learning the Vue Composition API and was wondering what the difference between `watchEffect` and `watch` is. Watch says it's the same as the Vue 2 watch, so I'm guessing watchEffect is like the 2.0 of that? I'm wondering if there is any specific cases where one would have great advantages over the other like in the case of stopping the watchEffect and then reactivating it instead of using a boolean in a regular watch... or are they just basically different ways of writing the same thing.

Thanks!

Reference:

watcheffect: https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#watcheffect

watch: https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#watch

Answer (score 24):

What helped me to understand the difference between `watch` and `watchEffect` in Vue 3 was to think about `watchEffect` as `computed` with side-effects.

> The `watchEffect()` hook works like the `computed()` hook or the `computed` option, but instead of returning a value, you use it to trigger side-effects.

Use `watch` whenever you want to trigger a side-effect when *a single* reactive value changes.

```js
// Triggers whenever `user` is updated.
watch(user, () => doSomething({ user: user.value, profile: profile.value }))
```

Use `watchEffect` whenever you need to watch *multiple* reactive values and trigger a side-effect whenever *any* of them is updated.

```js
// Triggers whenever `user` *or* `profile` is updated.
watchEffect(() => doSomething({ user: user.value, profile: profile.value }))
```

See: [watch vs. watchEffect when to use what with Vue.js](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/watch-vs-watcheffect-when-to-use-what-with-vue/)

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  On `watchEffect` how does vue.js know to only trigger on `user` and `profile` changes?  Are you sure  `watchEffect` doesn't trigger on every change to every computed property?

Comment: Yes, it triggers on every change to any reactive object inside the given callback function. `user`, and `profile` are the only two reactive objects in my example.

Comment: `triggers on every change to any reactive object inside the given callback function`, How can an outer function know about references inside an inner function?  I'm not sure you're correctly understanding what's going on here.

Comment: Yes, I’m sure that I know what’s going on on the surface of it. I don’t know exactly how it works behind the scenes. See: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#how-vue-tracks-these-changes

Comment: I agree understanding the internal mechanism is important. If a watchEffect calls another function which reads a number of properties, can the magic mechanism of Vuejs know what properties to watch?

Comment: @Gqqnbig yes, I think it can. The general idea is that all reactive objects in Vue are proxies - meaning whenever someone tries to access a property, the framework is notified of that access. The question is how the framework knows which method initiated the access and hence can track that method in order to invoke it again when the property changes. This is why any the logic that you want to re-run must be written eventually as something inside one of the `computed`, `watch`, or `watchEffect` methods.

Comment: @JamieMarshall That is exactly what the reactive system in Vue does. At a high level, the moment `watchEffect(yourMethod)` is invoked, Vue knows `yourMethod` is an effect and keeps it somewhere in a variable (imagine it is globally accessible). During the execution of `yourMethod`, whenever an reactive ref/object `X` is accessed, vue intercepts that access (because all reactive objects are proxies) and logs a dependency of form "`yourMethod` depends on `X`". Then going forward whenever X is changed again, yourMethod will be invoked again.

Comment: Why not use watchEffect() when you watch a single property? watchEffect will only trigger for the dependency inside the callback, witch can be a single property.

Comment: @gagarine in my example you can see, that there are multiple (two) reactive values used inside of the callback. Using `watchEffect` would trigger on changes to both of those reactive values. Which might or might not be what you want. If not, use `watch`. If you only use a single reactive value in the callback, and this happens to be the value you want to watch, you can use either `watch` or `watchEffect`. That's correct.

Comment: `watch` supports multiple sources so I'm still not sure re: differences. See https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watching-multiple-sources

Answer (score 14):

`watchEffect` seems to be a simplified `watch` and the main differences are

- Only accepts a function

  - `watch` can accept either a function or one or more reactive properties.
- Runs immediately when defined and when reactive dependencies change

  - `watch` only runs when reactive dependencies change

Answer (score 11):

`watchEffect` is something introduced in Vue3 with its composition api. The reason to have both `watchEffect` and `watch`, as I understand, is to keep the semantics of `watch` as close as possible to that of Vue2. The birth of watchEffect, if you are interested, can be traced back to [here](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/125#issuecomment-592288476) and [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/671)

As it stands today, `watchEffect` is an immediate/eager watch that uses a more concise/consistent syntax (consistent with computed):

1. `watchEffect` does not accept explicit watch sources, but instead automatically figures out all the dependencies by **immediately executing** the callback (or effect as how it is called in the source code), similar to how `computed` works. Therefore `watchEffect` **must run the effect immediately**. And because of this, there is a common trap (at least I have to keep reminding myself of it constantly) when setting up `watchEffect`: **you need to make sure that during the first execution of your `watchEffect`, all of the dependencies are indeed accessed**. How would some dependency escape from being accessed? Watch for conditional statements.
2. `watchEffect` will run its effect immediately as mentioned above.
3. `watchEffect` is a **deep** watch. This is something I am not sure whether it is intended or not. If you use a reactive object inside your effect, any change on that object will cause the effect to rerun, even if the changed property is not the one you accessed or is nested.

If Vue 3 is designed from scratch or there is no concern of maintaining backward compatibility, I would imagine there will only be `watchEffect`

Comment: Maybe, but `watchEffect` would probably provide a way to watch just one property.

Answer (score 10):

I would use:

- `watchEffect` when I want to watch multiple reactive properties and I don't care about old values
- `watch` when I want to watch one specific reactive properties and I may want old value

Note, above is what I would use them for, but may not be their only usage.

Also found in docs regarding the difference:

```
Compared to watchEffect, watch allows us to:

Perform the side effect lazily;
Be more specific about what state should trigger the watcher to re-run;
Access both the previous and current value of the watched state.
```

Source: https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#watch

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

- `watchEffect(callback)` will register the `callback()` as fireOnce-listener to all the properties accessed at the last execution of `callback()`. That is also the reason why the first execution of `callback()` is mandatory.
- `watch(refsArr, callback)` will register the `callback()` as a fireAlways-listener (unless `once=true` option is provided) to the reactive property/ies passed ( `refsArr`). The previous and current values of the reactive properties are provided to the `callback()`
- `watch(getter, callback)` will register the `getter()` as a fireOnce-listener to all the properties accessed at the last execution of `getter()`. The result of `getter()` determines whether callback will be executed (e.g. if it returns a value that is different from its previous execution). The return value of `getter()` does not affect any of the reactive properties nor is it mandatory that the returned value is anyhow related to them (though it is advised that it at least derives from them). If `getter()` returns always the same value, the corresponding  `callback()` will never fire. The `callback()` receives as arguments, the previous and current value returned by the `getter()` (not of the changed reactive property).

**Explanation:**

Without knowing any internals of `watchEffect()`, just based on some testing, I suspect, that whenever a reactive property is accessed, vue code inspects the stack-trace and if it sees that the access was initiated by a  callback registered with `watchEffect()`, it registers that callback to be run **once** when the specific property changes (this regisration could even be performed with `watch(ref,callback, {once:true})`)

Since the property-change will trigger again the above `callback()`, the registration will be repeated.

The above means that if one of the executions of the `callback()` passed to  `watchEffect()` does not read a reactive property, the `callback()` will never be executed again when the specific reactive property changes (unless some other reactive property fires the callback and inside that execution the above reactive property is accessed again).

**On the other hand:** The use of `watch(refsArray, callback)` will register the property change listener to the passed properties once and for all. Now if `watch` is used with in the form `watch(getter, callback)` the functionality is more close to `watchEffect()`.

**Practically the question should be:** What is the difference between watching for reactive property changes explicitly (directly passing them) vs  implicitly (passing a function that reads them). The behavior of the latter approach may cause some confusion and questioning on why some watchers stop reacting to changes.

Consider the following two cases. In Case1, `watch` mechanism will at some point stop working (when the randomly-generated value is `< 0.3`). The same for Case3 but with the decision being on `getter()`-side instead of `callback()`-side:

(Open the console and see what is printed when you write something to the input box. Try refreshing if the watch stops at the first keyup. As said in cases 1 and 3 watching will at some point stop.)

**[Case1 (click to test)](https://play.vuejs.org/#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):**

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

watchEffect(()=>{//callback
  let v = Math.random();
  console.log(`is ${v} > .3?`, v > .3);
  if(v > .3){
    console.log(msg.value)
  }else{
    console.log("watching of msg.value stops here, because the property was not accessed from inside the callback() passed to watchEffect(callback).");
  }
});

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg" />
</template>
```

[case2 (click to test)](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

watch([msg],()=>{//callback
  let v = Math.random();
  console.log(`is ${v} > .3?`, v > .3);
  if(v > .3){
    console.log(msg.value)
  }else{
    console.log("watching of msg.value will not stop even though the property was not accessed inside the callback() passed to watch(arr, callback).");
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg" />
</template>
```

[Case3 (click to test)](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

watch(()=>{
  let v = Math.random();
  console.log(`is ${v} > .3?`, v > .3);
  
  if(v > .3){
    console.log("value read from getter:", msg.value);
    return Math.random();
  }else{
    console.log("watching of msg.value stops here, because the reactive property was not accessed from inside the getter() passed to watch(getter, callback).");
  }
}, 
(current, prev)=>
    console.log("value:", msg.value, "currentFromGetter", current, "prevFromGetter", prev)
);
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg" />
</template>
```

With the above I don't anyhow imply that `watchEffect(callback)` or `watch(getter, callback)` have any issues or bad design. Just that, in order to use them, it is good to know how they work, to avoid pitfalls.